# Gradient control on instanced objects from collection

Tags: animation-nodes

So I have 10 different objects in the collection. I instanced them on the curve with different rotations and locations.
Now I'm trying to control the color over them with vertex color node. But what I'm not able to do is to control the color over the new distribution of objects. AN treats the new object list which is larger as consisting of those initial 10, thus when I move the falloff each new element gets colored according to its coloring in the original collection so no smooth gradient, but rather random one. Any thoughts how I can make AN treat the newly distributed instances as a separate group of objects to apply color animations to.
Thank you in advance.
Attached are the screens of node network and objects in the viewport:
[image: Shot 01 - left part of nodetree]

[image: Shot 02 - right part of nodetree]

[image: Shot 03 - how it looks in view port]

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to set a material to the created objects?

Comment: Omar, how one can be able to do that? When I apply a material to instance and copy to other instances the number of objects that this material is applied to stays as the original 10 objects. so no change. I was not able to wrap my mind how I can instance objects from group and at the same time retain Deep Copy capability. What am I missing here?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what the problem is or what you are trying to do. Can you maybe make a simplified example where the problem occur or rephrase your question?

Comment: I have 10 objects in collection which I randomly instance on spline with total amount of 120. After that I get 120 clones which have materials applied from originals, so with or without a loop I get uncontrolled random texturing. Is there is a way to override the coloring on newly created object instances or any other way to distribute objects but be able to apply colors to instances and not to original objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a deep copy of the meshes for each instance, get the meshes from the objects and write them to the instances using the *Mesh Object Output* node as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Omar, worked like a charm!! Thank you very much!